# Estimating underlying variance from a sample that includes Poisson noise

Tags: variance, estimation, poisson-distribution

I have a random variable $y$ which comes from a Gaussian distribution with some $\sigma_y$ and $\mu_y=-\frac{\sigma_y^2}{2}$. I then draw a sample $\{y_i\}$ from this distribution. Then for each sample I make one Poisson draw where $\lambda_i = \bar{N}\exp(y_i)$ for some $\bar{N}$. I now go back and try to estimate the original value of $y_i$ for each sample where $y_i' = \ln{N_i} - \ln{\bar{N}}$ which now includes Poisson noise. How do I estimate the true value of $\sigma_y$ from $\{y_i'\}$ and remove the Poisson contribution to $\text{Var}(\{y_i'\})$?